# How can I get syntax highlighting on CronTab when using Nano as Editor?

Tags: cron, nano, syntax-highlighting

Ubuntu, RaspBian and FreeBSD offer the user to choose editor on first `crontab -e` execution, so I selected **Nano Editor**.

But syntax highlighting seems **not** be enabled.
I tried the same parameter I use for Nano with no luck:

```
crontab -e --syntax=sh
crontab: illegal option -- -
crontab: usage error: unrecognized option
usage: crontab [-u user] file
       crontab [-u user] { -e | -l | -r }
```

How can I **enable syntax highlighting** for CronTab when using **Nano** as default editor?

Comment: Presumably you want to pass the `--syntax` argument to `nano`rather than to `crontab`: so `EDITOR='nano --syntax=sh' crontab -e`

Comment: @steeldriver : It fails returning: `crontab: nano --syntax=sh: No such file or directory
crontab: "nano --syntax=sh" exited with status 1` . Same results for `export VISUAL='nano --syntax=sh'`.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez works fine on Ubuntu. Which cron are you using? (`dpkg -S $(command -v crontab)` on Ubuntu or Raspbian, dunno about FreeBSD)

Comment: Works fine for me too, on Raspbian.

Comment: Indeed. It fails on FreeBSD, but works on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that with nano as the default editor for *crontab* the highlighting would not work.

To fix I added the following line to the */root/.bashrc* and *~/.bashrc* of the user.

```
export EDITOR='nano --syntax=sh'
```

Comment: Working on Ubuntu and RaspBian. Failing (no color syntax) on FreeBSD 10.3 .

Comment: Do You have the „include /etc/nano/sh.nanorc“ in the .nanorc file?

Comment: Indeed. The `~/.nanorc` contains `include "/usr/local/share/nano/*.nanorc"` , that is the path to all the syntax files.